# xsl template to remove entire node if it has empty attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that has multiple parent nodes and each node has different attributes. In addition I have few empty child nodes to these parent nodes and few empty headers i.e only parent node with attributes but no children.

I want to format it in such a way that my output XML will have no node with empty attribute i.e need an xsl template that deletes entire node If it enconters an empty attribute.

I have applied a template; that was able to remove only empty attributes but not the node that holds empty attribute. Also, 
when I tried to remove empty headers , it is deleting my empty child nodes too which I don't want!

So, I just need a template that deletes the node itself which holds an empty attribute.

Comment: Help us help you: Show your XML input, your current XSLT, and your desired XML output.

Comment: "*deletes entire node If it enconters an empty attribute*" Are you sure you want that? Delete any node with an empty attribute - even if it has other content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following generalized XSLT that runs an identity transform to copy entire document as is and runs empty template matches to remove the needed items. Should you need specific attribute or node, replace the `*` with the specific named item:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Removes all nodes with any empty text -->
  <xsl:template match="*[.='']"/>

  <!-- Removes all nodes with any empty attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@*='']"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly without seeing a sample, but the easiest way to remove a node is to not copy it. You can do this with a recursive copy template that omits the copy part if the appropriate attributes are empty.

Something like this (not tested) might do the trick.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@foo = ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Parfait's version is definitely a more purely XSLT-like way of doing it than this. I tend to do it this way for readability since it keeps all the logic in one template. Parfait's version would also make it easier to drop in new conditions for omitting content. My version would get messy if the rules for omission got complicated. His would then definitely be more readable.